# How to create/modify shortcut in a different location?

Tags: vbscript

**QUESTION**:

Currently, this VBScript works fine to change the icon of the shortcut `1.lnk` on the `DESKTOP` (`&H10&`) using the second icon in `2.dll`, but only on the `DESKTOP` (`&H10&`). How can I modify this script to replace `DESKTOP` and `&H10&` with the following Quick Launch location - `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch`?

If this is NOT possible, is there any other script that I can use to modify the icon on clicking the VBS script? Also, is it possible on the Taskbar instead = `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`?

The VBScript is as follows:

```
Const DESKTOP = &H10&

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(DESKTOP)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("1.lnk")
Set objShortcut = objFolderItem.GetLink
objShortcut.SetIconLocation "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\2.dll", 1
objShortcut.Save
```

P.S. In case anyone wants to know, I used [IcoFX 2](http://icofx.ro/downloads.html) in order to make the *.dll* file with different *.ico* icon files. In IcoFX 2, I just pressed Tools, then Icon Resource Editor, then New, then I right-clicked Add, then I added the *.ico* files, and finally I saved my *.icl* file. I then changed the *.icl* file to a *.dll* file by renaming it in WinRAR.

P.S.#2 I also included a separate question #2 and answer below which addresses the TaskBar issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Freddie, but I already solved this problem by following what a Yahoo Answers user, Me2, provided. I suggested that the user post their answer on Stack Overflow, but for now, here is the link to their wonderful answer: [link] (http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20170127192857AAybuef)

Comment: Post the answer and give attribution to the original source in your answer, that would be perfectly acceptable approach.

Comment: Please post the answer as an answer not as an edit to the question, that way it can be voted on and you can accept it as the answer to the question.

Comment: Looks fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ANSWER**:

Just as @Lankymart advised, I am posting the answer of Yahoo Answers* user, Me2:

> ```
> set wsSh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
>
> Folder = wsSh.SpecialFolders.Item("AppData") & "\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch"
> Set myShortcut = wsSh.CreateShortcut(Folder & "\1.lnk")
> MyShortcut.IconLocation = "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\2.dll, 1"
>
> myShortcut.Save
> ```

According to Yahoo Answers* user, Me2, the VBScript can also be written as follows:

> ```
> Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
> Set wsSh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
>
> location = wsSh.SpecialFolders.Item("AppData") & "\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch"
> Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(location)
> Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("1.lnk")
> Set objShortcut = objFolderItem.GetLink
> objShortcut.SetIconLocation "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\2.dll", 1
> objShortcut.Save
> ```

***Here is the [link](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20170127192857AAybuef) to the original answer source of Yahoo Answers user, Me2.***

Answer (score 1):

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace("C:\")
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("autoexec.bat")
msgbox objFolderItem
```

> **NameSpace Method**
>
> ---
>
> Creates and returns a Folder object for the specified folder.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> object.NameSpace vDir
> ```
>
> **Parameter Description**
>
> **object**  Required. An object expression that evaluates to a Shell object.
>
> **vDir**  Required. Specifies the folder for which to create the Folder object. This can be a string that specifies ***the path of the folder or one of the ShellSpecialFolderConstants values***.

Comment: If you are going to quote something please provide a link to the original source.

Comment: If it's not a quote why put it in a quote block? Only person at fault here is you, there is no need to get personal and call me names, those comments will be dealt with swiftly by the community.

Comment: What is with [quote block](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41906052/3)?

Answer (score 0):

**QUESTION #2**:

I posted this question to @Freddie and @Lankymart earlier, but I found the answer, which I want to share with everyone:

> Freddie or @Lankymart, do any of you know how to edit the 2 provided
>   answers above so that the icons on the TaskBar, which is located at
>   C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick
>   Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar get updated as well, just as in Quick
>   Launch? For now, I updated the Yahoo Answers user Me2 code to include
>   "\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar" but it
>   just updates the icon in the
>   C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick
>   Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar folder, not on the actual TaskBar. TaskBar
>   refuses to update.

**ANSWER #2 to QUESTION #2**:

Okay, this is the answer to my 2nd question: On the following [link](https://superuser.com/questions/499078/refresh-icon-cache-without-rebooting), a SuperUser by the name of Elmo suggested to run the following command `ie4uinit.exe -show` in Windows 10 to refresh the cache of the TaskBar's icons. For older versions of Windows, use `ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache`.

I made the following Batch file:

```
devmanview.exe /enable "USB\VID_012A&PID_034B\56789"
@echo off
color 0A
echo dddddd---ddd--dd-dddddd
echo dddddd-d-ddd-d-d-dddddd
echo dddddd---ddd-dd--dddddd
echo _______________________
echo ADAPTER = ON
pushd "C:\Users\Username\Desktop"
cscript X.vbs
ie4uinit.exe -show
timeout 4 > null
```

***EXPLANATION***:

This Batch file allows my shortcut's icon on the `TaskBar` to be changed when I press it indicating whether the following Adapter turns on or off. I ran the VBScript, named *X.vbs* (that the Yahoo Answers user Me2 helped with earlier) under this Batch file by using the command

```
pushd "C:\Users\Username\Desktop"
cscript X.vbs
```

I also included a little "ANSI drawing" after `@echo off` to indicate in green that the adapter is turned on.

The `ie4uinit.exe -show` allows the shortcut of the icon to refresh in the `TaskBar`, just like the `QuickLaunch` shortcut changes using the VBScript.

I used *devmanview.exe* to enable/disable the adapter under Device Manager. You can download *devmanview.exe* from [here](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/device_manager_view.html).